# Crossfade 3 images on hover

Tags: jquery, css, image, hover, cross-fade

I could not find a solution to this specifically, so I hope somebody can help me out.

I have 3 images and I would like to crossfade them from the first image to the second and to the third on mouse over or hover and stop there, and then cycle backwards on mouse out.

Mouse Over | Original Image > Image 2 > Image 3 | Stop

Mouse Out | Image 3 > Image 2 > Original Image | Stop

I imagine it would be best to use JQuery, but any solutions are welcome.

http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

Demo 1 here works rather well for two images, but because the images have transparent areas they overlap each other, but the fading effect between images is perfect.

UPDATE

I think Ive done it using CSS, based on the Demo 1 from that site, I did this

```
#Logo {position:absolute; z-index: 1; width: 250px; height: 120px;}
#Logo:after {content: ""; position: absolute; z-index: -1; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; background: url(images/Logo3.png); opacity: 0;
transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;}
#Logo:hover:after {opacity: 1;
transition: opacity .5s .65s ease-in-out;}
#Logo img.A {position:absolute;
transition: opacity .5s .65s ease-in-out;}
#Logo img.A:hover {opacity: 0;
transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;}

<div id="Logo"><img class="A" src="images/Logo.png"><img src="images/Logo2.png"></div>
```

This seems to work pretty well for my purposes, it fades out the first image leaving only the second image, and then fades in the third. Then does the same in reverse on mouse out. But I was wondering if this was the best way to go about it? or if it will have compatibility issues? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: why don't you save the images without the transparent areas, colouring those with the colour of your site's background?

Comment: Because its a logo that is above a dynamically changing background image.

Comment: sorry, that doesn't make much sense... how do you want it to cover what's behind, but at the same time still keep the transparent areas...?

Comment: I was hoping to use jquery, or whatever might work, to fade image 1 into image 2, remove image 1 and then fade image 2 into image 3. And then do it again in reverse on mouse out. The 3 images are similar in size and content, only a few words and the coloring change.